# Outputting Image in java

Tags: java, image, output

I have made a program in java that accepts a color image and converts it into gray scale image. The image is read as a BufferedImage, the RGB components are extracted and modified and set into the same image to display on the console window created. But I want the output as a separate jpeg or png file. Can someone tell me how to do this?

EDIT:

```html
    public static void saveToFile(BufferedImage img)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
          {
          File outputfile = new File("E:\\Java\\Sample.jpg");
          ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputfile);
          }
```

This was the method I was hoping to use .Here img was the image I was using(editing upon, i.e. changing pixel values).And the path where I want to store my output was E:\Java    .  Please Someone help..

Comment: @petric :Please don't indiscriminately down vote. This gives a setback to new users . Ask for something, if even then not received, then consider down voting..

Comment: @petric : Oops. I am extremely sorry. Your comment very much made me think that you were the down voter. Extremely sorry for everything. However, a request. You can always do a tiny favor by up voting(cancelling the down vote).:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this way:

```
{
    File outputfile = new File("E:\\Java\\Sample.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputfile);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close()
 }
```

Comment: Be carefull, I found, that png is not supported in OpenJdk 1.8